# .htaccess causes infinite loop on live server but works on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, godaddy

I'm a newbie .htaccess and regex. I have a script that works locally but when I upload it to a live server it causes an infinite loop. How can I fix this? On the site when you load `http://subdomain.example.com` if you are unauthenticated it takes you to `http://subdomain.example.com/auth/` for a login form, else it displays the contents of `http://subdomain.example.com/index.php`. It works fine locally but when I upload on a live server, it cannot find auth.php so it redirects to the index page and because the user is not authenticated it sends to auth.php thus the infinite loop. When I test my .htaccess from here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ the results are as shown below. Please advice. Please help. Thanks.

**This is my file**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   DirectoryIndex index.php
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /     

   # remove php extensions (only for GET method)
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.php(?:\?|\s) [NC] #This variable is not supported: %{THE_REQUEST}
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f #This variable is not supported: %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
   RewriteRule ^ %1/? [L,R=301] #This rule was not met because one of the conditions was not met

   # don't touch other existing files/folders
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR] #This variable is not supported: %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR] #This variable is not supported: %{REQUEST_FILENAME}
   RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} \d #This variable is not supported: %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}
   RewriteRule ^ - [L] #This rule was not met because one of the conditions was not met

   # force trailing slash
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f #This variable is not supported: %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php
   RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301] #This rule was not met because one of the conditions was not met

   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f #This variable is not supported: %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?a=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]#This rule was not met because one of the conditions was not met

   #rewrite path to file eg http://example.com/auth/recover to http://example.com/auth.php?a=recover
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f #This variable is not supported: %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php
   RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?a=$2 [QSA,L] #This rule was not met because one of the conditions was not met

   # rewrite extensionless php files
   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f #This variable is not supported: %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php
   RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1.php [L] #This rule was not met because one of the conditions was not met

   # finally, if not found
   RewriteRule . index.php [L] #This rule was met, the new url is http://subdomain.example.com/index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by just commenting some lines that were making the server append the root directory making the script being requested not to be found. The working script is down below.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       DirectoryIndex index.php
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /     

       # remove php extensions (only for GET method)
       RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.php(?:\?|\s) [NC]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
       RewriteRule ^ %1/? [L,R=301]

       # don't touch other existing files/folders
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
       RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} \d
       RewriteRule ^ - [L]

       # force trailing slash
       #RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
       RewriteRule ^(.+?[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]   

       #RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
       RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?a=$2&id=$3&att=$4 [QSA,L]

       #RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
       RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?a=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L]

       #rewrite path to file eg http://example.com/auth/recover to http://example.com/auth.php?a=recover
       #RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
       RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?a=$2 [QSA,L]

       # rewrite extensionless php files
       #RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
       RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1.php [L]

       # finally, if not found
       RewriteRule . index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```